# resolve local hostnames from vpn client

Tags: vpn, dns, resolv.conf

when I connect to a openvpn server I cannot resolve loacl hosts in my LAN. I can rather ping the IP's and ssh to the IP. My `/etc/reslov.conf` when connected to openvpn:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 172.16.10.1
nameserver 10.0.10.1
search company.domain local.domain
```

I can of course resolve any host in the company, but not in my LAN although my local nameserver is listed in `/etc/resolv.conf`. Now I am using `/etc/hosts` for that, which is fine, since they are only 10 hosts.
Some times I need to connect to my openvpn server from the company, and I have to disconnect if I want to do any task in one of the hosts, since hosts in LAN cannot be resolved and I cannot add ~3000 hosts to my `/etc/hosts`. `/etc/rresolv.conf` looks then like this:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.0.10.1
nameserver 172.16.10.1
search local.domain company.domain
```

Is there any way to solve this without using a local `dnsmasq` for instance and without using `/etc/hosts`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done with just the libc built-in resolver. Whichever way you order the name­servers, if the first one responds with "No such domain" the resolver *will not* try the other one.

You don't specifically need dnsmasq, but you *do* need some sort of auxiliary DNS resolver which can track name­servers per domain. Common alternatives are Unbound and systemd-resolved.

The easiest choice might be systemd-resolved (with DNSSEC=no), because it provides a replacement for resolvconf for automatically importing the configuration, and integrates with NetworkManager (if you use it for VPN).

Comment: That makes sense. I'll go for it. Thanks a lot